# Android Navigation Bar Not Disappearing OnResume

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have the navigation/action bar completely disappeared. But when someone swipes down from the top to reveal the action and navigation bar, a few seconds later the top bit disappears but the nav bar stays..

I'm not sure if this is to do with onResume, I presume not as the code works in it's normal usage.. Code and image snapshot below:

**OnResume (same code copied in onCreate):**

```
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

**XML Theme:**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

**After navigation bar is swiped..**
[image]

Comment: i don't see here actionbar. tyr to remove: | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION

Comment: Sorry I mean navigation bar! let me re-write the question, tried your suggestion and it still does it..

Comment: still does it because also this should be deleted (my personal opinion):             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar

Comment: But then the nav bar is there all the time? I just tried it.

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html) guide from Google.

Comment: Tried the guides.. none are responding to the UI changes..........

Answer (score 1):

```
 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Use immersive sticky and all is resolved.